# In twilio video, is there a way to distinguish whether a remote participant was disconnected deliberately vs. due to network error?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-video

I am using twilio video js sdk v2.0.0 to build video chat application in the browser. I got basic things up but I'd like to detect if possible whether the remote participant was disconnected on purpose (eg. because he/she clicked the "hangup" button) vs. disconnected due to some network error (eg. wifi problems) or other kind of non graceful disconnection such as when user clicks the refresh button on browser.

The reason I'd like to do this is to be able to differently handle each disconnection event for other user(s):
- when disconnect was on purpose I would automatically disconnect the other participant (in one-to-one chat)
- when disconnect happened because of some error I'd like to keep other user in waiting state for a minute or two just to give the first user a chance to reconnect and continue the video chat

Is this possible to do with twilio video?